# Alternative for `rep(x, each=n)` when `n` is a vector

Tags: r

I need to replicate certain data a certain number of times depending on the row of the data. For instance, I have the following code

`max.vals <- sapply(1:length(data), function(x) rep(data[[x]], length.out=iterate[[x]]))`

And data is a list of vectors of the form:

```
data[[1]]
[1] 1.2838 1.1451 1.1619 

data[[2]]
[1]  121.46 120.46 121.45
```

And integer is a list of vectors of the same row length as `data[[i]]`

```
[[1]]
[1] 5  5  3  

[[2]]
 [1]  1 1 2
```

And I want output such that `1.2838` is repeated 5 times, `1.1451` is repeated 5 times and so on:

```
[[1]]
1.2838 1.2838 1.2838 1.2838 1.2838 1.1451 1.1451 1.1451 1.1451 1.1451...

[[2]]
121.46 120.46 121.45 121.45
```

However, the code `max.vals <- sapply(1:length(data), function(x) rep(data[[x]], length.out=iterate[[x]]))` ends up repeating the series using the first element of integer. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: My bad. I got it into a list of data.frames. However, I'm a little confused with the function you provided. For some reason, it's repeating the sequence 1.2838 1.1451.. instead of repeating the values independently.

Comment: Next time, please try to provide your data in more easily reproduced form, like the "Data" section of Richard's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `Map()`, the multivariate `lapply()`.  This will run `rep()` one-to-one on the elements of each list.

```
Map(rep, data, iterate)
# [[1]]
#  [1] 1.2838 1.2838 1.2838 1.2838 1.2838 1.1451 1.1451 1.1451 1.1451 1.1451
# [11] 1.1619 1.1619 1.1619
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 121.46 120.46 121.45 121.45
```

Data:

```
data <- list(c(1.2838, 1.1451, 1.1619), c(121.46, 120.46, 121.45)) 
iterate <- list(c(5, 5, 3), c(1, 1, 2))
```

Comment: Thank you so, so, so much! I was stuck on this for so long and I never realized there would be such a simple solution.

Comment: This also seems to work: `Vectorize(rep.int)(data, iterate)`